# How to create a list for each inputted item in dictionary - Python?

Tags: python

I am making a student grading dictionary where the grades for each student should be stored in the dictionary created earlier under the student ID, along side the name of the student. ex. {'1234': {'Name': 'Josh', 'Scores': [88,99,77]}} I am relatively new to coding so dont know how much of my code to share, and it is probably much longer than it needs to be right now.

```
myDict = {}
total_scores=[]
all_names=[]
total_student_id=[]
for key in total_student_id: 
    for value in all_names: 
        myDict[key] = value 
        all_names.remove(value) 
        break 
for key in all_names: 
    for value in total_scores: 
        myDict[key] = value2 
        total_scores.remove(value2) 
        break 

new_student=True 
more_grades = False
while new_student:
    name = input("What is their name?")
    all_names.append(name)
    student_id = input("What is their student id?")
    total_student_id.append(student_id)
    repeat1 = input("Are there any more students? yes or no: ")
    if repeat1 == "no": 
        new_student = False
        more_grades = True
    else:
        new_student = True
while more_grades == True:
    assignments = int(input("How many assignments were given: "))
    assign_number = 0
    while assign_number < assignments: 
        score = int(input("enter one of your assignment scores: "))
        total_scores.append(score)
        assign_number = assign_number+1
        more_grades = False
        continue
for key, value in myDict.items():
    print(key, ' : ', value, value2)
```

Currently, this code is set up to take the input for each student, and their id. It also asks for the number of assignments given along with the grades for each assignment, however it does not ask for the grades of each specific student. I want to switch this code to ask each student individually for their grades, and add it to the dictionary, to get an output similar to the one i mentioned above.
Edit: I am also having the problem of it not printing out any results at the end. Originally, it was printing out the student id and name, but once I started implementing the assignments/scores, the code would end once I added the final score.

Current Output:

```
What is their name?Andrew
What is their student id?101
Are there any more students? yes or no: yes
What is their name?Dani
What is their student id?102
Are there any more students? yes or no: yes
What is their name?George
What is their student id?103
Are there any more students? yes or no: no
How many assignments were given: 3
enter one of your assignment scores: 22
enter one of your assignment scores: 88
enter one of your assignment scores: 55
```

Expected Output:

```
Please enter the student's name: Andrew
Please enter the student's ID: 101
Enter another student? (y)es (n)o: y
Please enter the student's name: Dani
Please enter the student's ID: 102
Enter another student? (y)es (n)o: n
How many assignments were given? 3

Please enter the scores for Andrew
Enter score (0-100) for assignment 1: 90
Enter score (0-100) for assignment 2: 88
Enter score (0-100) for assignment 3: 95

Please enter the scores for Dani
Enter score (0-100) for assignment 1: 56
Enter score (0-100) for assignment 2: 70
Enter score (0-100) for assignment 3: 85

Final grade report:
Andrew's average score was 91.0
Dani's average score was 70.3

Assignment averages:
The average for assignment 1 was 73.0
The average for assignment 2 was 79.0
The average for assignment 3 was 90.0
```

Comment: Hi can you please share the expected output? and how is it different from the current output

Comment: I updated the problem to show the output i am getting, I couldnt go to a new line in the comments. It is basically ending the code once i enter the final assignment, and not applying it to the dictionary

Comment: So how would the final dictionary look like? can you post a JSON maybe

Comment: Being embarrassingly honest, I am very new to coding and stackoverflow, I am not 100% certain how to add a JSON file properly. The next best thing  I can think of is to send this information of what I am needing to do. https://prnt.sc/sat73k The final dictionary would simply be similar to this: {'1234': {'Name': 'Josh', 'Scores': [88,99,77]}} for each student, so in my case it would be... {'101': {'Name': 'Andrew', 'Scores': [##,##,##]}} {'102': {'Name': 'Dani', 'Scores': [##,##,##]}} {'103': {'Name': 'George', 'Scores': [##,##,##]}} Sorry if this is not much help.

Comment: Edit the question to add the information you just mentioned in your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went through your image and I just ended up writing the code.

```
def main():
    students_left_to_log = int(input("How many students would you like to log?\n"))

    student_collection = {}
    while students_left_to_log > 0:
        student_id = input("Student Id: \n")
        name = input("Student Name: \n")
        assignment_left_to_log = int(input("How many assignments were given?\n"))
        assignment_counter = 1
        student_data = {'Name': name, 'Scores': []}
        while assignment_left_to_log > 0:

            # maybe use a try except block here avoid errors
            score = int(input(f"Enter their score on assignment {assignment_counter}: \n"))

            if score > 100 or score < 0:
                print("The scores must be between 0 and 100.")
                continue

            student_data['Scores'].append(score)
            # reduce the number of assignments left to log
            assignment_left_to_log -= 1
            assignment_counter += 1

        # reduce the number of students left
        students_left_to_log -= 1
        student_collection[student_id] = student_data
        print(f"Successfully logged student: {student_id}\n\n")

    for student_id, student_data in student_collection.items():
        avg_score = round(sum(student_data['Scores']) / len(student_data['Scores']), 1)
        print(f"Student {student_data['Name']} avg assignment score: {avg_score}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Some concepts you'd wana go through:

- Error Handling in python (The try except blocks)
- String interpolation python (The nifty `f""` syntax)
- `round()` built-in method
- Maybe some JSON fundamentals (since it's very similar to python `dict`) read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_json.asp)

Comment: Oh my god dude haha, your insane. I know its really not that complicated of a code, but ive been struggling with it for a while now. Thank you very much, and im definitley going to be looking into those concepts you mentioned. This virus cut alot of the stuff we were learning in class short, and Ive definitley struggled in the class since it got out. Thanks again, definitley going to be studying python more over the summer before classes start again.